# how to check internet availability in j2me

Tags: java-me, mobile, gprs

How to check internet availability on mobile application.... in j2me....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this property for detect the available GPRS connection on s40 series mobiles.

```
com.nokia.network.access
```

Its returns the networking access point type. the possible values for this property are:

```
* pd — Packet data, for example GPRS
* csd — Circuit-switched data, for example GSM CSD/HSCSD data call
* bt_pan — Bluetooth PAN network
* na — Not applicable, the implementation cannot determine the type r
```

For more info see this [wiki link](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/TSJ000306_-_MIDP:_System_properties).

Also you try to access url to verify that. If you got timeout or any connection related exception means the type of network is not available.

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard way in JavaME of doing this. You might want to check custom vendor libraries, e.g. Symbian JavaME libraries.

You can try to ping a server or try to make a connection and catch the exception. But this doesn't give any indication whether the phone is generally capable of connecting to the internet or not. It just tells you, that you can't connect at that moment.

Comment: Hmm, I'd have said this was totally reliable.  Try a connection...  connection works = internet available, exception thrown = no availability, surely.

Comment: well, imagine him setting a flag "internet_available = false;" even though the user was just in a tunnel.

Comment: Having said that, I've reworded my answer a bit to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Try just making a connection and see if it throws an exception.

Comment: The best way to demonstrate thanks round here is to upvote and accept.

Comment: Upvoted! I think your answer is more reliable. If the phone itself doesn't have any internet connection, e.g the user disallow it, we could throw exception and say "This application need internet connection"